# scala repl setting and logs

Tags: scala, scala-repl

My scala repl is not showing the logs on the screen as some books and forums seem to suggest. I am on scala 2.12.1. My scala repl when I try below syntax

```
scala> def sum(a:Int, b:Int) = a+ b
sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int
```

Should show as below

```
scala> val fun2 = sum _
fun2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

But it is showing as below:

```
scala> val fun2 = sum _
fun2: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1623/2005055216@13bdf19
```

It is not showing the trait like `<function2>` etc. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is due to the way Scala 2.12 now SAM converts Scala functions SAM interfaces. If you want to see the type of an expression, prepend `:t` to the declaration:

```
scala> :t val fun2 = sum _
(Int, Int) => Int
```

Comment: but it is not showing the things like <function2> and all still. Can you tell why and how to fix that?

Comment: `(Int, Int) => Int` is syntax sugar for `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`. I am not sure there is a way to roll back to previous presentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala 2.12 type checker accepts a function literal as a valid expression for any Single Abstract Method (SAM) type, in addition to the FunctionN types from standard library. This improves the experience of using libraries written for Java 8 in Scala.

```
scala> val runRunnable: Runnable = () => println("Run!")
```

runRunnable: Runnable = $$Lambda$1073/754978432@7cf283e1

scala> runRunnable.run()
Run!